# Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") while inetgrating with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grails

I am new to groovy with grails and I am trying to integrate postgresql. I am getting an exception

> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver**

at this line :

```
   Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BuildConfig.groovy file you need to add :

> runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'

in 
**dependencies {
}**

For eg :

```
dependencies {

    runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'

}
```